# Creating plist file for table or collection view data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, plist

I am currently building a plist file to be used for a table or collection view data source.

The idea is to have a bunch of categories and each category would have different information associated against it. For example, categoryName, categoryImageName, categoryInfo (all strings for example sake).

**Question**
What is the correct way to set this out in the plist? Would I create a dictionary for each category named 'category' and then the relevant sections within it, or differently?

Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>category</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CategoryName</key>
        <string>Restaurants</string>
        <key>CategoryImageName</key>
        <string>image1</string>
    </dict>
    <key>category</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CategoryName</key>
        <string>Test Category 2</string>
        <key>CategoryImageName</key>
        <string>image2</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why note create this as JSON and add that file as part of your project? Its fast to load and parse with built in iOS elements.

Comment: Can you confirm the advantage of using JSON over a plist? Witha  plist I can directly add and edit in the UI in xcode for example and access with contents of file

Comment: I feel that json is easier to use vs XML based items. I know Xcode has built in editing for a plist, but it depends on where you are getting your data from too. If it comes from a database or server, you can easily get that JSON and save it. If there is an API, call the get method and save the data from Safari as a file.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is more of an opinion than an answer to the actual question here. This is static data and not served from an API/server so JSON is irrelevant in fact as you can directly edit in a UI in Xcode the plist is the easiest route to use. Thanks though